# Compare Value of Current and Previous Row, and after for Column if required in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select the value of one column based on the values ​​of other rows and other columns.

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,"051",0,0,10,0),(1,"052",0,0,0,0),(2,"053",10,0,10,0),(2,"054",0,0,10,0),(3,"055",100,50,0,0),(3,"056",100,10,0,0),(3,"057",100,20,0,0),(4,"058",70,15,0,0),(4,"059",70,15,0,20),(4,"060",70,15,0,0)).toDF("id","code","value_1","value_2","value_3","Value_4")
scala> df.show()
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  1| 052|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0|
|  2| 054|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|
|  3| 056|    100|     10|      0|      0| 
|  3| 057|    100|     20|      0|      0| 
|  4| 058|     70|     15|      0|      0| 
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20| 
|  4| 060|     70|     15|      0|      0| 
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Calculation Logic:**

Select a code for an id, following the steps

1. For each column n(value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4), do
2. For the same id look for the maximum value in the value_n column
3. If the maximum value is repeated, the next column is evaluated
4. Otherwise, if the maximum value is found without repetition, the id and the code of the column with the maximum value are taken. It is no longer necessary to evaluate the following columns.

**Expected Output:**

```
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

In case of id 3:

- It has the codes 055, 056, 057
- value_1 has the values ​​100 for all three codes, so the maximum value is 100 but it repeats for all three codes, I can't select a code.
- The value_2 column has to be evaluated, which has the values ​​50,10 and 20 for each code respectively
- So the maximum value is 50 among the three codes, and it is unique.
- The record with id 3 and code 055 is selected

Please help.

Comment: I dont quite understand what "maximum value is repeated" in step 3 means. Maybe you could add some more example data?

Comment: Hi werner, add three records with id 3 and a little explanation. I hope it is better understood. Thank you.

Comment: are all the numbers only natural numbers or do you have -ves and decimals too?

Comment: Hi C.S.Reddy Gadipally, also decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your value_1 to 4 in a struct and call max function on it groupedBy id column using window

```
scala> df.show
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  1| 052|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0|
|  2| 054|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|
|  3| 056|    100|     10|      0|      0|
|  3| 057|    100|     20|      0|      0|
|  4| 058|     70|     15|      0|      0|
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20|
|  4| 060|     70|     15|      0|      0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+


scala> val dfWithVals = df.withColumn("values", struct($"value_1", $"value_2", $"value_3", $"value_4"))
dfWithVals: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, code: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> dfWithVals.show
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|         values|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|  [0, 0, 10, 0]|
|  1| 052|      0|      0|      0|      0|   [0, 0, 0, 0]|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0| [10, 0, 10, 0]|
|  2| 054|      0|      0|     10|      0|  [0, 0, 10, 0]|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|[100, 50, 0, 0]|
|  3| 056|    100|     10|      0|      0|[100, 10, 0, 0]|
|  3| 057|    100|     20|      0|      0|[100, 20, 0, 0]|
|  4| 058|     70|     15|      0|      0| [70, 15, 0, 0]|
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20|[70, 15, 0, 20]|
|  4| 060|     70|     15|      0|      0| [70, 15, 0, 0]|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+


scala> val overColumns =org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy("id")
overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@de0daca

scala> dfWithVals.withColumn("maxvals", max($"values").over(overColumns)).filter($"values" === $"maxvals").show
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+      
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|         values|        maxvals|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|  [0, 0, 10, 0]|  [0, 0, 10, 0]|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|[100, 50, 0, 0]|[100, 50, 0, 0]|
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20|[70, 15, 0, 20]|[70, 15, 0, 20]|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0| [10, 0, 10, 0]| [10, 0, 10, 0]|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+



scala> dfWithVals.withColumn("maxvals", max($"values").over(overColumns)).filter($"values" === $"maxvals").drop("values", "maxvals").show
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+                                      
| id|code|value_1|value_2|value_3|Value_4|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1| 051|      0|      0|     10|      0|
|  3| 055|    100|     50|      0|      0|
|  4| 059|     70|     15|      0|     20|
|  2| 053|     10|      0|     10|      0|
+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, you have really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in a form that algorithm is guaranteed to select always one column, the following code produces the expected result:

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy("id")

var df2 = df;
val cols = Seq("value_1", "value_2", "value_3", "value_4")
for( col <- cols) {
  df2 = df2.withColumn(s"${col}_max", max(col).over(w))
    .withColumn(s"${col}_avg", avg(col).over(w))
}

var sel = ""
for( col <- cols) {
  sel += s"(${col}_max <> ${col}_avg and ${col} = ${col}_max) or"
}
sel.dropRight(2)

df2.filter(sel).select("id", ("code" +: cols):_*).sort("id", "code").show
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond, they help me a lot with your answers.